# redeploay prebuild app with another technology like flutter as an update to the old app in app store and playstore

Tags: android, ios, flutter, app-store-connect, google-play-console

I have an app in play and app store which is built with react native.
Now i recreated the whole App using flutter.
My question is. Can i deploay the flutter version app as an update to the react native? the bundle id is the same as the react native, but i am not sure about ios certificates.

Do i need the exact certifoicate which is built with react native? or the certificate doesnt matter as long as i have the same bundle id? If i sign it with my certificate and deploy it will it be available as an update or as a whole new App. And the same with android what do i need for android?

Will be very happay if anybody can help me by this.

Answer (score 1):

For both plattforms, the technology doesn't matter. You can develop android and iOS apps with Kotlin (multiplattform), Java (Android), Swift (iOS), .Net MAUI, React Native, Flutter, Unity / Unreal / Godot and whatever else you can find.

But in order to count as an update to an existing app, your new app needs to:

- have the same bundle ID / application ID
- use the same keystore / signing certificate
- have a greater version number than the previous app

Comment: beside of the second point i have everything. Because i dont have access to the old certificate/keystore. It means then i am also not able to push it as an update to the old version?

Comment: That is correct. Both, the Google Play Store and Apple App store, as well as the devices themself will not accept your app as an update. So even side loading an APK directly onto an Android device would not allow you to install an app as an update.